# Display Column and Return Column LOV

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working in Oracle APEX(Application Express). When I want to create a List of Values (LOV) it gives me only one option for displaying and returning value. Is there any method in APEX so that it can Display me more than one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to display more than 1 column by default.

- You could alter your lov query to concatenate multiple column values into a display columns

  ```
  select empno return_value, empno||': '||ename||' - '||job display_value
  from emp
  ```

  You can steer markup through the Popup LOV template too, if you'd want to use a fixed width font.
- Use a plugin such as the [SkillBuilders SuperLov](http://skillbuilders.com/oracle-apex/Application-Express-APEX-Consulting-Training.cfm?tab=free-plugin-downloads). However, this plugin does not work in tabular forms.
- Roll your own by using for example modal pages (again, SkillBuilders have an [excellent plugin for modal pages](http://skillbuilders.com/oracle-apex/Application-Express-APEX-Consulting-Training.cfm?tab=free-plugin-downloads)), or through the use of javascript (ex creating new windows and handling returns)